# SetUnhandledExceptionFilter in office addin

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, ms-office

How can I set `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` for my office add-in, so that I can report exceptions/write dumps for my add-in only (i.e. set it on entering add-in's code, restore on leaving the add-in's code)?

I have googled around a bit, and found out that starting with 2007 office "patches" the `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` function to be a stub, thus preventing override. Check the discussion [here](http://microsoft.public.office.developer.com.add-ins.narkive.com/gpZX6HYM/setunhandledexceptionfilter-in-office-addin) for example.

How can I do it "the unsupported way"? I.e. how can I restore that function to what it originally was (to OS function), and then call it?

I've found similar article about "fixing" AutoCad here (it does the same "trick" of patching `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`): http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/02/overriding-the-setunhandledexceptionfilter-for-autocad.html

Would be good to get similar info on office, or any other ideas how to get minidumps on unhandled exceptions without signing up for windows error reporting (WER).

Comment: Why are you not handling exceptions before they leave your add in?

Comment: Of course I am :) But there are random crashes from time to tome at some customers environment which I want to be able to collect.

Comment: Windows Error Reporting provides everything you are asking for (including collecting minidumps). What is the rationale behind side-stepping the standard error reporting facilities?

Comment: $500 certificate, and corporate customers without internet connection

Comment: `__try {your addin code here} __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {your exception handling code here}`

Comment: Thanks, but does this provide information about the source of the problem, i.e. if I write minidump in that exception handler, won't it be already too late?

Comment: No, it isn't too late. This is your first chance to handle the exception. The entire callstack is still intact. You need to read up on [Structured Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657.aspx). However, this will also catch page faults when accessing the stack's guard page. This is likely not something your application survives in good shape.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: SEH looks okay, but needs to be set on every entry point, which is a bit troublesome (every entry function needs to be doubled so that try/__try are not mixed in one function?). Could somebody say something about AddVectoredExceptionHandler ? It also seems to work (is not intercepted), and needs to be set only once?